# Have group permission but unable to create file

Tags: permissions, directory-structure

I found a strange thing while playing with pi3B.
I want to create a file in `/sys/class/gpio` (*just poking around, no specific reason*) but I get a **Permission Denied**. Below is some information.

```
pi@raspberrypi:/sys/class/gpio $ groups
pi adm dialout cdrom sudo audio video plugdev games users input netdev gpio i2c spi
pi@raspberrypi:/sys/class/gpio $ ls -ld .
drwxrwx--- 2 root gpio 0 May  6 00:28 .
pi@raspberrypi:/sys/class/gpio $ touch somefile
touch: cannot touch 'somefile': Permission denied
```

As you can see, I am in group **gpio** and the group has the write permission of directory `/sys/class/gpio`.

So the question is Why I can't create new files in `/sys/class/gpio` even if the group I am a part of has the permission.

I tried relogin and reboot after add the **pi** user to group **gpio** and that's several days ago.

OS: raspbian stretch

tried `newgrp`
[image: newgrp]

Comment: Have you try with `newgrp gpio` command (and then `touch ...`)?

Comment: @RomeoNinov just tried, see Edit.

Comment: We see that. But you have posted an image. Please avoid that and post text version whenever available.

Comment: @Vlastimil OK I will pay attention to that next time(original text is gone now). thx.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

## `/sys` directory is special. You can't just poke around and create files

[Wikipedia excerpt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard#Directory_structure):

> Modern Linux distributions include a `/sys` directory as a virtual filesystem (`sysfs`, comparable to `/proc`, which is a `procfs`), which stores and allows modification of the devices connected to the system, whereas many traditional UNIX and Unix-like operating systems use `/sys` as a symbolic link to the kernel source tree.

Entries in `/sys` are created by the kernel and by drivers; you cannot just create them from the command-line. You might edit some as root, but you cannot generally make new ones from userspace except by loading kernel modules or otherwise installing drivers or modifying the kernel.

Comment: Just noticed that I cannot create files even when I am root. That explains a lot. Thanks.